# Laravel production.ERROR exception while trying to create a new user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When i'm trying to insert a user into my default users table, i get a 500 error and this can be seen in as a log in app/storage/logs directory:

```
[2016-02-10 10:03:52] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function connection() on a non-object' in /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2922
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

What is  the main reason of this and how can i solve this ?

**app.php**

```
'providers' => array(
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
                'Mews\Captcha\CaptchaServiceProvider',
                'Yangqi\Htmldom\HtmldomServiceProvider',
                'Maxxscho\LaravelTcpdf\LaravelTcpdfServiceProvider',
                'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',
    ),
```

**controller.php**

```
$instance = new myModal;
$instance->user = Input::get('username');
$instance->password = Hash::make(Input::get('pw'));
$instance->user_name = Input::get('username');
$instance->user_e_mail = Input::get('usermail');
$instance->save();
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('insertuser/{year}/{user}', array(
        'as' => 'insertuser',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@insertUser'
    ));
```

---Update---

**myModal.php**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class myModal extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
   use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
   protected $table = 'user_table';
   protected $primaryKey = 'primary_key';
   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $increments = 'primary_key';
   protected $fillable = array(
      'user'
      'password'
      'user_name'
      'user_e_mail '
   )
}
```

---Update 2---
that caused the problem in my controller:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'tr_TR.utf8');
```

so, i changed this as following:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'tr_TR.utf8');
//other stuff
setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.utf8");
```

and the problem solved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make sure that Laravel is able to access the database? try fetch something. also, can you take a look on your `.env` file? there should be a line like `debug=false`. i wonder if it works on `debug=true` just like [this case](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/issues/87), but it'd be weird. i'm intrigued with this.

Comment: @Tezla this is not the platform you can insult people or their questions. You just can share your knowledge.

Comment: Could you post the code you used for `myModal` class?

Comment: @phaberest sure, i updated the post.

Comment: Have you set the `.env` correctly?

Comment: @phaberest No problem with my .env file but i had to use a setlocale function in my controller. I've solved the problem.

Comment: @phaberest post about .env and i will surely accept that as an answer.

Comment: @blankBird_ Thanks, but it wouldn't be fair ;) You catched yourself what was causing the problem :D Happy to hear you solved, anyway